# The best practise how to write USE database Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like know the best practise how to resolve this problem.
I have many sql scripts for procedures, function, etc. (Every object has stand alone script).
In the first lines I have this code:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
```

This code is necessary for direct running.
I Also have init.bat file where I call every script.
In bat file are some properties and one of them is server name.
I can create simply all object to different servers.

But I would like create all objects on same server to another database.
I Do not want copy all files with different USE database code.
Is there any way how can I do it.
I thought about SYNONYM of database, but this is impossible.

Do you have any advice?
Thank you
David

Comment: Remove `Use MyDB` from every script. But select a database through a connection string in your bat file.